# Modify searchbox results view in UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I am working on my application update and I want to use a new searchbox and I want to show my results like Windows Store . 
[image]
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AutoSuggestBox which is bound to a changing ObservableCollection everytime the Text inside the AutoSuggestBox is changed.

For example, this is your Model:

```
public class App
{
    public ind Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public Image Picture { get; set; }        
}
```

You can implement a method updating an ObservableCollection with a parameter (in this case the search expression) in your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            SuggestedApps = new ObservableCollection<App>();
            SuggestedApps.CollectionChanged += SuggestedApps_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void SuggestedApps_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("SuggestedApps");
        }

        private ObservableCollection<App> suggestedApps;

        public ObservableCollection<App> SuggestedApps
        {
            get
            {
                return suggestedApps;
            }
            set
            {
                suggestedApps = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SuggestedApps");
            }
        }

        public void SuggestForSearch(string searchExpression)
        {
            SuggestedApps.Clear();


            //Assumgin EF as DataSource
            //You can use another Search algorithm here instead of String.Contains
            foreach(var item in yourDataSource.Apps.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchExpression.Trim())))
            {
                SuggestedApps.Add(item);
            }

        }


        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

In your Xaml code you can use this to bind an AutoSuggestBox to it and define a Template:

```
                <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxApps" ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestedApps}" TextChanged="AutoSuggestBoxApps_TextChanged">
                    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                </AutoSuggestBox>
```

In the implemetation of the TextChanged-Event you just call the SuggestForSearch Method from your ViewModel:

```
private void AutoSuggestBoxApps_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            (this.DataContext as ViewModel).SuggestForSearch((sender as AutoSuggestBox).Text); 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your great code . when I type something in the search box it will return me an error while running AutoSuggestBoxApps_TextChanged
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Universal4Khune.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DataContext is Null

Comment: OK , Problem  solved by using this code: 

            AutoSuggestBoxApps.DataContext = new ViewModel();

Comment: this Answer is fully functioning , but those who want to use it like me only change this line : public Image Picture { get; set; }  to : public BitmapImage Picture { get; set; } . Again thank you and marked as Answer

Comment: Just to mention: This is a rudimentary solution. If you have a big amount of Data here, it will return a big amount of data when a single letter is typed into the AutoSuggestBox. So you can adjust this for your requirements. For example if you type an "a" it will return every app with an "a" in its name. So you can check how many letters are in AutoSuggestBox.Text and define a minimum for example 3 letters. If you still get too many results you can sort them by popularity or something and then Take the first 50.

Comment: Thanks . Is it possible to for example show only 4 or 5 number of results here and then add some options like See more results at the bottom of the search results ? 
When user tap on show more results it shows results in a separated page ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a control for UWP named AutoSuggestBox that you should read up on: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx

This should give you the tools you need to give the wanted functionality

Comment: Thanks for your response :)